# Get legacyPageContext in JS Console

Tags: modern-experience

In SPFx/Typescript we can use `this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext` to get the old `_spPageContextInfo`. But how can I get hold of this if I am just working in the browser console on a modern page (i.e. without Typescript or SPFx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
window.spModuleLoader._bundledComponents["b6917cb1-93a0-4b97-a84d-7cf49975d4ec"].PageManager._instance.pageContext.legacyPageContext
```

But I'd recommend adding [an application customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions) that defines all the required context variables globally in your own namespace.

Comment: Thanks! Had to look up the GUID. For anyone else curious: The "modern" pages are delivered by using the Site Pages web scoped feature (`B6917CB1-93A0-4B97-A84D-7CF49975D4EC`)